# Tag "energy" - is it appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [three questions tagged "energy"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy).

I first thought they would be related to some (unknown to me) concept of "energy of neural networks" or "energy measure of classification algorthms", or something similar. :)

Too bad, they are all related to electricity, electrical energy.

I think this tag should be removed, right?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that if "energy" has any usage in this topic, it's when talking about ideas borrowed from other fields like the energy of a Hopfield network or something. It doesn't get used much.

Is it wrong to tag a data science question about energy usage with "energy"? I don't think it's wrong, or at least not detracting. It's not like there's a common usage of "energy" that this is mixed up with.

I suppose I'd leave it until there's a minor conflict in usage.